# NodeJS MongoDB populate() bringing string instead of JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose-populate

I have a product and I have a property that brings an array with a provider id and its price. The idea is that every product has an array with multiples providers, each one with its own price.

However, when I use populate() looking for ProviderID, it brings me populated as string instead of a JSON. Below is GraphQL query return from a query that bring products.

[image: GRAPHQL return]

ProviderPrice class, inside ProductModel

[image]

Optional parameter in ProductModel

[image]

This is how I am executing populate

[image]

Has anyone gone through this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was using the class ProviderPrice instead of the model ProviderPriceModel.